# roslyn compiler for vs2017 install

Tags: visual-studio-2017

How to install roslyn compiler for vs2017? 
I am getting error for the missing file on  c:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\MSBuild\15.0\Bin\Roslyn\Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Microsoft.CSharp.Core.targets missing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47260114/microsoft-csharp-core-targets-missing)